# How to get selected values from a table row in a table layout in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am a beginner in xamarin android,I want to get the data in a particular row in the table layout.

Please help me..

Here is my Adapter code

```
 public class CaseDetailsAdapter : BaseAdapter<CaseDetails>
{ 
    private readonly Activity context;
    private readonly List<CaseDetails> _cases;
    int _count;
    public  TableRow _row;

    public static TableLayout _tbLayout;
    public  TextView _value;
    public TableLayout _temp;

    public CaseDetailsAdapter(Activity context, List<CaseDetails> model)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this._cases = model;
    }

    public List<CaseDetails> GetList()
    {
        return _cases;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _cases.Count; }
    }

    public override CaseDetails this[int position]
    {
        get { return _cases[position]; }
    }


    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cases[position].Description) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cases[position].Title) && _cases[position].Files != null)
        {
            _count = (_cases[position].Files).Count;

             view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DetailsTable, null);

             _temp = (TableLayout)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tablelayout_file);
             _row = new TableRow(context);              
            _row.SetPadding(10, 0, 10, 0); 
            _row.LayoutParameters = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent);

            for (int i = 1; i <= _count; i++)
            {
                _row = new TableRow(context);
                _row.SetPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
                _row.LayoutParameters = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FillParent);

                TextView _title = new TextView(context);
                string _tempTitle = (_cases[position].Files.ElementAt(i).Title);
                _title.Text = _tempTitle + "\n";
                _title.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.border);
                _title.Id = i ;

                _row.AddView(_title);

                _value = new TextView(context);

                string _tempValue = (_cases[position].Files.ElementAt(i).Value);

                if (_tempValue.Length > 35)
                {
                    _value.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(_tempValue, ".{35}", "$0\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    int _length = _tempValue.Length;

                    for (int j = _length; j < 35; j++)
                    {
                        _valueImgName = _tempValue + " ";
                    }
                    _value.Text = _valueImgName + "\n";
                }

                _value.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.border);

                 _row.AddView(_value);
                _temp.AddView(_row);
                  _row.Click += _row_Click;

            }                
        }

        else
        {
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CaseDetailsDesign, null);

           //else case code...
        }

        return view;                  
   } private void _row_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //not working
    }

}
```

When I clicking row in the  table layout,I want to get the contents in that row  (`_value.text`). And the DetailsTable is located in a single row of a list view.How could I get the data.I think here didn't assign a id to the textview or table row may be that's the reason can't get the data.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please show us you've tried to help yourself. I see nothing indicating you've actually tried to write code to do this, or researched how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `GetChildAt()` method in your click event.
For example:

```
        private void _row_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)sender;
            TextView title = (TextView)tableRow.GetChildAt(0);
            TextView value = (TextView)tableRow.GetChildAt(1);
        }
```